# Binding to a combobox and allow editing: Selected Item becomes empty

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, combobox

I have a problem with some binding, I have `ObservableCollection` of strings with all my combobox dropdown items. It should be possible to either select a value from the dropdown menu or insert some text manually or combine both methods.

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding AvailableAddressSymbols}" 
    Text="{Binding SelectedItem.LowerBound,
        ElementName=combobox_sys_data_protection}"
    HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
    IsEditable="True"
    DropDownOpened="SymbolAddressRefress_Dropdownopend" />
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding AvailableAddressSymbols}" 
    Text="{Binding SelectedItem.UpperBound,
        ElementName=combobox_sys_code_protection}"
    IsEditable="True"
    DropDownOpened="SymbolAddressRefress_Dropdownopend" />
```

I'm binding to the text property of that combobox to allow manually written text. Everything works fine, but I have more than one of these comboboxes.
The available Items for the combobox get refreshed on drop down opened.

Now here comes the problem: When I select a value in combobox1 and I want to select a value in combobox2 then the vaule from combobox1 is set to " ";

The refresh clears the itemlist and adds the new values, I think here is the problem but I need to refresh it because there will maybe new values.

```
    internal void refreshAvailableAddressSymbols()
    {
        AvailableAddressSymbols.Clear();
        for (int i = 0; 
             i < Database.ProjectConfiguration.AddressSymbols.Count;
             i++)
        {
          AvailableAddressSymbols.Add(
            Database.ProjectConfiguration
                .AddressSymbols[i].StartAddress);
          AvailableAddressSymbols.Add(
            Database.ProjectConfiguration
               .AddressSymbols[i].EndAddress);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Some background:

With a `ComboBox` in WPF the `SelectedItem` must be one of the dropdown-`Items` all the time.

This means: In the moment you `Clear()` the ObservalCollection bound to `ItemsSource` the condition above no longer holds and `ComboBox` clears `SelecetdItem`.

To avoid this, there are two strategies:

1. Remember your selected item in a local variable, Clear your items,
   set items to a new set ans then set SelectedItem to an item now
   available in the dropdown list.
2. Do not `Clear()` your itmes but *update* the list (adding new,
   removing old elemnnts). As long as you don't remove the
   `SelectedItem`everything works fine

Comment: Is there maybe a better solution than using a combobox? I just want to have some standard values, and the user should be able to edit them....